# Nokia Here Geocoder API - Partial postalcode search

Tags: here-api

We are using Geocoder API from Nokia Here maps and we are trying to search an address from a partial postalcode (we'd like using 'begins with' partial postalcode).

We are using this:

http://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.xml?postalcode=0400&country=ES&gen=5&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg

With 4 digit postalcode search we are obtaining results but if we search by 3 digits, we are getting no results:
http://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.xml?postalcode=040&country=ES&gen=5&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg

Is there any other way to do this?

Any help would be great!
Thanks in advance,

Antonio Sanchez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in that 3 digits is considered to be insufficient infromation to obtain a result.
I guess that If Spanish Postal Codes are purely numeric, you could make ten requests and amalgmate the results:

- [http://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.xml?postalcode=0400&country=ES&gen=5&app_id=XXX&app_code=XXX](http://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.xml?postalcode=0400&country=ES&gen=5&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg)
- [http://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.xml?postalcode=0401&country=ES&gen=5&app_id=XXX&app_code=XXX](http://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.xml?postalcode=0401&country=ES&gen=5&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg)
- etc.